# regex to validate i/p string as PDC-<GroupName>-Team1 or PDC-<GroupName>-Team2 or PDC-<GroupName>-Team3

Tags: regex

I have to build such a regex where I can validate the i/p string should be in format...

PDC--Team1
or
PDC--Team2
or
PDC--Team3

GroupName can be any alphanumeric string with only "-" allowed to use.

I am currently trying with ^PDC-[A-Za-z0-9-]+-Team1$|[A-Za-z0-9-]+-Team2$|[A-Za-z0-9-]+-Team3$ but this not working as expected..

If someone knows how to this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
^PDC-[A-Za-z0-9-]*-Team[0-9]$
```

So we start with **PDC-**, capture anything in between and end with **-Team** and a number.

I guessed that groups can go higher than 3, else change the last group to [1-3], If it can go higher than 9 then add a * after the group for any number.

Comment: only problem is "PDC-dfds-Team1-Team2" also matching but I want that it should match only PDC-dfds-Team1 or PDC-dfds-Team2 or PDC-dfds-Team3 and not the combination of teams. Also it should not match PDC-PDC-dfds-Team1 only single PDC is required.

Answer (score 0):

I found it somehow working with `^PDC-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*-(Team1|Team2|Team3)$`. Just still the enhancement is to allow PDC- only at start and only for single time.

Comment: You are explicitly allowing the combination of PDC- within the group, because you allow A-Z and a -. What are some possible examples you are expecting inside the group?